# Word/Phrase for searching for some support for something

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

How can we state that we are searching for some supporting evidence for something? For example, in the following sentence:

> This may cause some errors in the evaluations. However, we do not aim at providing an independent evaluation method and just **seek some support** for our previous results.

I sense that "seek some support" is good, but it doesn't seem that it's widely used in that meaning according to Google.

Comment: As written, I don't fully understand your sentence.  What do you mean by "we don't aim at providing an independent evaluation method"?  Are you asking other people to **validate** or **verify** your results?  How can they do this if you don't provide them an evaluation method?  Are they supposed to develop these methods on their own?

Comment: No, I'm not asking others. In our next experiment, we try to find some supporting evidence for the results of the previous experiment. For that I wrote "seek some support".

Comment: I'm still unclear.  Are you just trying to **reproduce** the results of the previous experiment?  Reproducing other scientists' work is common, as it **corroborates** the original experiment.  Otherwise something like "corroborate" is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest "corroborate"

> **[corroborate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/corroborate)** (v): Confirm or give support to (a statement, theory, or finding)

In this case:

> Our goal is not to provide a method for independent evaluation, but simply to **corroborate** our previous results.

Other possibilities:  *confirm, verify, validate*.  Similar words with a slightly different meaning:

> *authenticate* (make sure something is real and true),
>
> *substantiate* (make sure something has real and significant evidence),
>
> *justify* (provide a good reason for (doing) something)
>
> *certify* (add a kind of "official" stamp of validity)
>
> *document* (add written support for something)